# Package Execution via POWERSHELL

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis

I am trying to execute an SSIS package via Powershell. I also proceed some parameters to it. I use the following command:

```
DTExec /ISSERVER "\SSISDB\folderB\Integration Services Project17\Package.dtsx" /SERVER "." /Envreference 2 /Par "$Project::ProjectParameter(Int32)";1 /Par "Parameter(Int32)";21 /Par "CM.sqlcldb2.SSIS_repro.InitialCatalog";ssisdb /Par "$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)";True
```

I replaced the parameters with the ones I need and when I try to execute it it tells me that the parameter `CM.sqlcldb2.SSIS_repro.InitialCatalog` does not exist. I found somewhere on the internet that this parameter is related to a `Connection Manager`. But which connection manager? Does anybody knows the meaning of that parameter?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Run `DTExecUI` (a GUI for dtexec) and open the SSIS package within that.

In the DTExecUI GUI, can you see that `CM.sqlcldb2.SSIS_repro` exists as a connection manager?

DTExecUI will give you the ability to manually edit all editable parameters/configurations.

Once you have amended all parameters/config, the last section of DtExecUI called 'Command Line' will give you the resultant command line, which can then be passed in to `dtexec'. You can copy and paste this and use in PowerShell (or where ever).

Also, the parameters have some double quotes, which contain words starting with `$`. PowerShell will try and interpolate these as variables.

Try this:

```
$dtexecParams = @(
    '/ISSERVER',     "\SSISDB\folderB\Integration Services Project17\Package.dtsx"
  , '/SERVER',       '.'
  , '/Envreference', '2'
  , '/Par',          '"$Project::ProjectParameter(Int32)";1'
  , '/Par',          '"Parameter(Int32)";21'
  , '/Par',          '"CM.sqlcldb2.SSIS_repro.InitialCatalog";ssisdb'
  , '/Par',          '"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)";True'
)
@dtexec $dtexecParams
```

...where I've wrapped up parameters that need double quotes, in single quotes, to stop the interpolation. I've also created an array of parameters to pass into the `dtexec` command, so it's easier to see what's being passed in.

Comment: Thank you for your answe TechSpud. I run DTExecUI and it gives me options for packge source from where I can not find the package. I can not adress a package on SSIS Catalog. How can I do that?

Comment: Not sure. Try instead, using SSMS to browse the Integration Services Catalog, then right-click on the package and choose Configure. This will show you the connection managers and the available properties. Could it be that the type of connection you're trying to set, does not have an InitialCatalog property?